# How MySQL Output Group by Date in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hy Guys,

How MySQL query for Group by Date in CodeIgniter and display list the result?

Example :
http://prntscr.com/jio4eo

Answer (score 0):

That's the way that the framework display the data. Getting the distinct dates and getting all the events togheter; The Direct Query I would do is

Select date from events group By date;

Select distinct(id), title, description from events group By date;

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, so I've no idea what you would hope to achieve with this.

Comment: Distinct is a SQL function as Count

Comment: Functions have arguments. DISTINCT can take no arguments. So the parentheses are redundant (and misleading).

Answer (score 0):

use group by

```
$this->db->select('COL1, COUNT(COL1) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('COL1'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $this->db->get('tablename', 10);
```